# Buscar coincidencias entre Strings <JAVA>

Tags: java, string, comparaciones

tengo un proyecto en el cual tengo que buscar coincidencias de caracteres entre 3 diferentes Strings apartir de 4 caracteres por ejemplo:

```
String cadena1 = "aaattkggl"
String cadena2 = "rrattkmmt"
String cadena3 = "wwattkkllg"
```

como se puede observar entre las 3 cadenas se encuentran los caracteres "attk" y el programa deberia imprimir "attk".

en caso de tener mas de 4 caracteres unidos en las 3 cadenas deberia imprimirlos, ejemplo:

```
String cadena1 = "cadenaxyuiop"
String cadena2 = "qwertcadenaxqwert"
String cadena3 = "asdfghcadenax"
```

se deberia imprimir: "cadenax"

gracias a otro usuario pude avanzar con este codigo:

```
    //Pedir datos al usuario y validarlos
    System.out.print("Ingrese primer cadena: ");
    cadena1 = leer.nextLine();
    if (cadena1.contains("b")||cadena1.contains("j")||cadena1.contains("Ã±")||cadena1.contains("x")||cadena1.contains("z"))
    {
        System.out.println("La cadena contiene caracteres invalidos");
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("\n");
        System.out.print("Ingrese segunda cadena: ");
        cadena2 = leer.nextLine();
        if (cadena2.contains("b")||cadena2.contains("j")||cadena2.contains("ñ")||cadena2.contains("x")||cadena2.contains("z"))
        {
            System.out.println("La cadena contiene caracteres invalidos");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("\n");
            System.out.print("Ingrese tercer cadena: ");
            cadena3 = leer.nextLine();
            if (cadena3.contains("b")||cadena3.contains("j")||cadena3.contains("ñ")||cadena3.contains("x")||cadena3.contains("z"))
            {
                System.out.println("La cadena contiene caracteres invalidos");
            }

            //dividir la cadena en 4 caracteres y compararlos con las otras cadenas
            else 
            {
                System.out.println("\n***************************************************");
                for (int i=4; i<cadena1.length();i++)
                {
                    String[] partes = cadena1.split("(?<=\\G.{" + i + "})");
                    for (String parte : partes)
                    {
                        if (parte.length() < 4) break;
                        if(cadena2.contains(parte)&&cadena3.contains(parte))
                        cadenator.add(parte);
                    }
                }
            }

            System.out.println(cadenator);
        }
    }
}
```

pero no logro que pueda imprimir el resultado esperado con cualquier cadena, como la del primer ejemplo.

de igual manera deberia poder imprimir varias coincidencias en el caso de haberlas, ejemplo:

```
String cadena1 = "holaxxxxxxamigo"
String cadena2 = "amigottttttttthola"
String cadena3 = "ggggggggholagamigo"
```

esto deberia imprimir "hola" - "amigo"

Si alguien podria ayudarme, lo agradeceria muchisimo.

Comment: Si es una tarea para ingenería de sistemas, lo tienes permitido de usar expresiónes regulares? Podrías mostrar los esfuerzos de código que has hecho para solucionar el problema? Puedes tratar de especificar más preciso que es una "similtud" en tu contexto? (Por ejemplo cuantos caracteres en fila tienen que ser iguales para contar como similtud)

Comment: debe haber una similitud de 4 caracteres en las 3 cadenas por ejemplo:

cadena1 = kkasjdkjdasHOLAasdasoijdasd
cadena 2 = HOLAkdashdshowqeppopoip
cadena 3 = xzvczvxcxzvczxbvzcxbHOLA

en las 3 cadenas hay similitud de 4 caracteres juntos que forman la palabra HOLA, no se si me di a entender?

Comment: Mínimo y máximo 4 caracteres?

Comment: @Dev.Joel mínimo 4 caracteres, por ejemplo si tienes [HOLAAXXXXX] [KKKKKKKHOLAA] [YYYYHOLAAYYY] deberia imprimir: "HOLAA"

Comment: Hola , Erick probó la ultima actualización de mi respuesta en su pregunta anterior ? en el ejemplo que expone si es de **4 a más caracteres** debería imprimir `hola , amig, amigo ,migo`

Comment: Hola Joel, si implemente tu codigo al mio pero sigue sin mostrar los resultados esperados. tiene un poco mas de nivel de complejidad ya que deberia poder identificar el numero de caracteres (minimo3) y mostrarlos, como mencione en el ultimo ejemplo el resultado que necesito obtener seria "hola" y "amigo" y no "holaamigo" ya que en ninguna cadena estan unidos todos los caracteres. ni tampoco deberia imprimir "hola , amig, amigo ,migo". este proyecto lo dejó un maestro de quimica de la carrera de ISC para poder exentar 2 unidades de la materia y nadie a parte de mi pudo avanzar algo,

Comment: Pero no se entiende , te contradices. dices que quieres que muestre `hola`  `amigo` , que tome en cuenta mínimo tres , o sea se pueden repetir `4 5 6 ..` caracteres y debería seguir mostrando. eso hace mi ejemplo. `hola, amig, amigo, migo` tiene más de 4 caracteres y se repiten en las tres cadenas

Comment: Y Ojo en la pregunta anterior especificaste *Minimo 4* ahora *Minimo 3* entonces por qué mostraria `hola` y no `hol`?

Comment: A lo que me refiero es que se considere como coincidencia un grupo de 4 caracteres como minimo, osea que a partir de 4 caracteres se empiece a formar una coincidencia. ejemplo: podría ser coincidencia: "hola - stackoverflow - prueba" pero no podría considerarse una coincidencia "hey - top - sas" y por lo tanto no deberia imprimir ningun resultado en caso de encontrarse en todas las cadenas. mil disculpas por los errores del post, ya mismo los corrigo y elimino el post duplicado. si es necesario que algun moderador corriga o elimine los post en caso de infligir alguna regla.

Comment: al introducir estas cadenas no funciona: [aaattkggl] - [rrattkmmt] - [wwattkkllg] no imprime nada y deberia mostrar: "attk"

Comment: @ErickLugoJ Insisto , modifico su método con mi ultima actualización ? mi segunda parte de mi respuesta? probé y efectivamente esa es la salida de mi programa.

Comment: @ErickLugoJ - Por favor, intenta probar las soluciones que recibiste en tu pregunta anterior, incluyendo las actializaciones (sí, hay que copiar el último código y pegarlo en la parte relevante del primero)... Por otro lado, estás haciendo la misma pregunta por duplicado. ¿Podrías editar tu primer pregunta e incluir la información relevante?

Comment: Hola @Dev.Joel acabo de probar de nuevo todo el código editado y ya funciona con las cadenas que me dio el maestro, solo hay un grupo de cadenas que me da un problema pero creo que se como resolverlo. de nuevo, muchas gracias.

Comment: @Mariano intente eliminar una pregunta para evitar el duplicado pero al parecer no tengo permisos para realizar esa accion, voy a editar correctamente la primera para poder eliminar esta pregunta. Gracias y perdón.

Comment: Votando para reabrir, ya que está cerrada como duplicada de una que se combinó con esta.

Answer (score 1):

Básicamente lo que hace este código es separar la primera cadena en partes desde 4 caracteres hacia adelante haciendo uso de una expresión regular `(?<=\\G.{" + numerodecaracteres+ "})` teniendo esas partes se hace uso del método [contains](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains(java.lang.CharSequence)) de la clase String. sí dicha parte  se encuentra en las otras dos cadenas se imprime.

```
String One, Two, Three;
System.out.print("Ingrese cadena de aminoacidos numero 1: ");
One= leer.nextLine();

System.out.print("Ingrese cadena de aminoacidos numero 2: ");
Two= leer.nextLine();

System.out.print("Ingrese cadena de aminoacidos numero 3: ");
Three= leer.nextLine();
List<String> repeats= new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < One.length(); i++) { 
    for (int j = 4; j < One.length(); j++) {
        String[] parts = One.substring(i,One.length()).split("(?<=\\G.{" + j + "})");
        String part= parts[0];
        if(part.length()<4) break;
        if(Two.contains(part) && Three.contains(part)){
            if(!repeats.contains(part)) repeats.add(part);
        }
   }
}
```

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56795/discussion-on-answer-by-dev-joel-buscar-las-coincidencias-de-maximo-tamano-con).

Answer (score 1):

Creo que esto te puede ayudar:

```
package cm;

public class Temp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final String cadena1 = "cadenaxyuiop";
        final String cadena2 = "qwertcadenaxqwert";
        final String cadena3 = "asdfghcadenax";
        final String cadena4 = "cadenaxPorPaolo";

        final String[] cadenas = {cadena1, cadena2, cadena3, cadena4};
        String coincidencia = "";
        String coincidenciaFinal = "";

        for (int i = 1; i &lt; cadenas.length; i++) { // no es necesario comprobar la primera cadena

            if (!(coincidencia.length() > 0)) {
                final String cadena = cadenas[i];
                final String cadenaAnterior = cadenas[i - 1];

                for (int z = 0; z &lt; cadenaAnterior.length(); z++) { // se recorre la cadena anterior
                    final String caracterEvaluar = String.valueOf(cadenaAnterior.charAt(z));

                    // se hace la comprobacion de coincidencias
                    if (coincidencia.equals(cadena)) { 
                        if (cadena.contains(coincidencia)) {
                            coincidencia += caracterEvaluar;
                        }
                    } else {
                        if (cadena.contains(caracterEvaluar)) {
                            coincidenciaFinal += caracterEvaluar;
                            coincidencia = caracterEvaluar;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Coincidencia: " + coincidenciaFinal);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hola Paolo, lo acabo de testear y luce bien, déjame probar con otras cadenas y te comento el resultado final, gracias.

Comment: Recueda que debes meterle mano aún a este código.

Comment: si lo se, creo que se puede notar mi inexperiencia pero es que apenas estoy aprendiendo en la universidad. si, todavía tengo que adaptarlo a lo que pidió mi maestro, pero lo que enviaste es la parte crucial de el programa.

Comment: Lo vivo ahora, ¡Aún nos queda mucho que aprender muchacho!

Comment: Hola de nuevo Paolo, acabo de probar tu código con diferentes cadenas y pude notar que no imprime los resultados esperados. como por ejemplo con las cadenas: "aaattkggl" - "rrattkmmt" - "wwattkkllg" deberia imprimir: "attk" ya que como puedes observar en las 3 cadenas son los caracteres que se repiten.

Comment: Te he dicho que debías meter mano al código,. Un consejo: Este código verifica carácter a carácter las posible coincidencias, de manera que podrías obtener fallos. Esto es una idea, no la solución al problema, eso debes hallarla tu.

Answer (score 1):

Una alternativa asegurando coincidencias de maximo tamaño para *n* Strings

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;


public class StringFind {

    private String[] strings;

    public StringFind(String... strings){
        this.strings=strings;
    }

    private String match(String string){
        // buscar string en strings[1]-strings[length-1];
        int found = 1;
        for (int i = 1; i<strings.length; i++){
            if (strings[i].contains(string)) found++;
        }
        return (found == strings.length) ? string : null;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getMatches(){
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        String lastMatch="";
        // recorrer substrings desde 0
        for (int i = 0; i<strings[0].length()-4; i++){
            String resto = strings[0].substring(i);
            // buscar substring hasta minimo tamaño 4
            for (int j = resto.length(); j>3; j--){
                // buscar en otras cadenas
                String match = match(resto.substring(0, j));
                // ignorar si es parte del ultimo resultado agregado
                if (match!=null && !lastMatch.contains(match) ){
                    // recordar y agregar
                    lastMatch=match;
                    list.add(match);
                }
            }
        }
        return list;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        StringFind sf = new StringFind("holaxxxxxxamigo", "amigottttttttthola", "ggggggggholagamigo");
        ArrayList<String> list = sf.getMatches();
        Iterator i = list.iterator();
        while(i.hasNext()){
            System.out.println(i.next());
        }

    }

}
```

Salida:

```
hola
amigo
```

Comment: lo pruebo y te comento, te agradezco por comentarlo.

Answer (score 1):

El problema que quieres resolver se llama [**Longest common substring (LCS)**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_substring_problem) (no confundir con [**Longest Common Subsequence**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem)). Un algoritmo para hacer esto luce como el siguiente:

*(He modificado algunas partes para que muestre todas las coincidencias)*

```java
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s1 = "holaxperrxquetlssaxxxxamigos";
        String s2 = "amigottttquetlssatttttperrholas";

        System.out.println(allLongestCommonSubstring(s1, s2));
    }

    private static ArrayList allLongestCommonSubstring(String s1, String s2) {
        ArrayList<String> palabras = new ArrayList<>();

        ciclo:
        // recorrer caracter por caracter el string "s1"
        for (int i = 0, ilargo = s1.length(); i < ilargo; i++) {
            // para cada caracter de "s1" recorrer todos los de "s2"
            for (int j = 0, jlargo = s2.length(); j < jlargo; j++) {

                // contador de maximo
                int max = 0;

                // comparar "s1" frente a "s2" para encontrar la palabra
                while (s1.charAt(i + max) == s2.charAt(j + max)) {

                    // por cada coincidencia aumentar el maximo
                    max++;

                    // pero si el maximo excede el largo de algunos de los strings, romper el ciclo
                    if ((i + max >= ilargo) || (j + max >= jlargo)) {
                        break;
                    }
                }

                // si la cantidad de coincidencias es mayor que 3
                if (max > 3) {
                    // obtener la cadenas desde i hasta donde terminan de coincidir (i+max)
                    palabras.add(s1.substring(i, (i + max)));

                    if (i + max >= ilargo) {
                        // si está al final, saltar los caracteres que quedan y romper el ciclo
                        break ciclo;
                    } else {
                        // si no, saltar la palabra encontrada
                        i += (i + max < ilargo) ? max : 0;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return palabras;
    }
}
```

Puedes ver [mas implementaciones en la Wiki](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Strings/Longest_common_substring).

Comment: Iba a responder en la otra pregunta, pero la cerraron :( Te recomiendo que le pongas el nombre de la otra a esta, ya que explica mejor lo que quieres hacer :P

Comment: Hola @arie CwHat muchas gracias por tu codigo comentado, ya edite las dos preguntas y trate de eliminar la segunda pero no puedo hacerlo porque ya tiene respuestas. tu codigo me resultó mas fácil de entender porque esta a mi nivel (estoy en segundo semestre en la uni) a comparación de lo que otros usuarios me han compartido que tuve que  investigar sobre algunas partes. un saludo.

Comment: Como esta función devuelve un arrayList (un arreglo dinámico) puedes encontrar las coincidencias por pares : s1 - s2, s1 - s3. Luego intersectas los arreglos con una función como la que está en [esta respuesta](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5283123/6658955)

Answer (score 0):

llego con un par de años de retraso, me gustó el desafio, hay un problema con el planteamiento, se deben buscar las palabras más largas, por lo que en el caso de "hola amigo", solo se puede devolver "amigo hola", ya que si buscamos primero las más cortas, nos devolvería "hola amig migo amigo".

```
String buscarCoincidencias( String cadenaA, String cadenaB, String cadenaC, String resultado ) {
   int longTexto = cadenaA.length();
   for( int longPalabra = longTexto; longPalabra > 3; longPalabra-- ) {
      for( int k = 0; k <= longTexto - longPalabra; k++ ) {
         String subCadena = cadenaA.substring( k, k + longPalabra );
            System.out.println( subCadena );
         if( cotejar( subCadena, cadenaB ) && cotejar( subCadena, cadenaC ) ) {
            if( resultado.equals( "" )) {
               resultado = subCadena; 
            }
            else {
               resultado += ","+ subCadena;
            }
            cadenaA = cadenaA.replace( subCadena, "" );
            System.out.println( cadenaA );
            if( cadenaA.length() < 4 ) {
               return resultado;
            }
            return buscarCoincidencias( cadenaA, cadenaB, cadenaC, resultado );
         }
      }
   }
   return resultado;
}
  
boolean cotejar( String textoParaBuscar, String textoEnQueBuscar ) {
   int longTexto = textoEnQueBuscar.length();
   for( int longPalabra = longTexto; longPalabra > 3; longPalabra-- ) {
      for( int k = 0; k <= longTexto - longPalabra; k++ ) {            
         if( textoParaBuscar.equals( textoEnQueBuscar.substring( k, k + longPalabra ) ) ) {
            return true;
         }
      }
   }
   return false;
}
```

El funcionamiento es bastante sencillo, en ambos métodos, los for externos se usan para determinar el largo de la subcadena, empezando de la más larga posible y acortando hasta llegar a un tamaño de "4".
En el for interno, vamos generando las subcadenas, partiendo desde "k" hasta "k" más el largo que nos determina el for externo.
Lo que resta es hacer las comparaciones, en caso de haber coincidencias se quita la cadena encontrada del texto recibido y se vuelve a llamar al método con la nueva cadena.